# Loading PE Headers

Tags: c, winapi, portable-executable

Basically, what I am trying to do is to find last section of PE file. I have read PE specification very attentively, yet I can't discover where my code fails.

```
PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pidh = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)buffer;
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pinh = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)(pidh + pidh->e_lfanew);
PIMAGE_FILE_HEADER pifh = (PIMAGE_FILE_HEADER)&pinh->FileHeader;
PIMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER pioh = (PIMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER)&pinh->OptionalHeader;
PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER pish = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)(pinh + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS) + (pifh->NumberOfSections - 1) * sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER));
```

`buffer` is a byte array containing loaded executable, and `pish` is a pointer to the last section. For some reason, it appears that number of sections is over 20 000.

Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: "I can't discover where my code fails." - how does it fail?

Comment: Like i said, number of sections is over 20k. Thus, when dereferencing members of `pish` program crashes.

Comment: Why do you need a declaration for `pifh` and `pioh` while it's contained in `PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS`? And `sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS)` only get the size needed to allocating.

Comment: And how do you get the sections number?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is one problem I see off hand: e_lfanew is the offset to the `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS` structure in *bytes*. You are adding this number of bytes to a `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER` pointer, so you are moving forward by `sizeof(IMAGE_DOS_HEADER)*pidh->e_lfanew` bytes.

Fixed version:

```
PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pidh = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)buffer;
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pinh = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((BYTE*)pidh + pidh->e_lfanew);
PIMAGE_FILE_HEADER pifh = (PIMAGE_FILE_HEADER)&pinh->FileHeader;
PIMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER pioh = (PIMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER)&pinh->OptionalHeader;
PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER pish = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)((BYTE*)pinh + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS) + (pifh->NumberOfSections - 1) * sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER));
```

The best way to debug problems like this is to drop into the code with your debugger and view the PE data yourself in memory. You can open up the Visual Studio hex editor for example and see all of the byte data, and which values you are actually reading out.

Here's some information on viewing program memory in VS 2010:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3aw423e.aspx

Comment: Well, thank you very much, it appears that problem is in my (not)knowing of pointer arithmetic. :)

Comment: @jowo is `e_magic` from `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER` supposed to match the `Magic` of the `IMAGE_FILE_HEADER`? If so, I don't know why I'm getting incorrect behavior. I've loaded my EXE into a `std::vector<char> bytes` object and tried to set `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* img_dos_header = (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*)&bytes[0];` but the magic numbers don't align with my `IMAGE_FILE_HEADER* coff_file_header = (IMAGE_FILE_HEADER*)&bytes[coff_file_header_offset];`, which is definitely loading the correct info. Any idea what I need to fix? Or an alternate way to load the IMAGE_DOS_HEADER?

Comment: Ok, so, `e_magic` for `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER` is actually the _signature_ for the PE format... so `&bytes[0]` was actually correct , evaluating to `0x5A4D` :)

Comment: This was a good read, btw: http://what-when-how.com/windows-forensic-analysis/executable-file-analysis-windows-forensic-analysis-part-2/

Comment: Ok, last question ^_^ Why did you cast `pidh` to `(BYTE*)` when getting the NT header? Trying to follow the thought-process for future potential questions.

Comment: Reread the first paragraph and read about pointer arithmetic. If I had an integer pointer and added 1, it would move the address forward 4 bytes. If it were a double pointer, it would move forward 8 bytes. If it were a byte pointer, it would move forward 1 byte. Since e_lfanew is the number of *bytes* to move forward, we need to convert pidh to a byte pointer. Otherwise, since pidh is a pointer to a structure, adding N would move forward by N*structure_size bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Various section address and data can be obtained by below way also :

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    LPCSTR fileName="inputFile.exe";
    HANDLE hFile;
    HANDLE hFileMapping;
    LPVOID lpFileBase;
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS peHeader;
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER sectionHeader;

    hFile = CreateFileA(fileName,GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);

    if(hFile==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::cout<<"\n CreateFile failed \n";
        return 1;
    }

    hFileMapping = CreateFileMapping(hFile,NULL,PAGE_READONLY,0,0,NULL);

    if(hFileMapping==0)
    {
        std::cout<<"\n CreateFileMapping failed \n";
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return 1;
    }

    lpFileBase = MapViewOfFile(hFileMapping,FILE_MAP_READ,0,0,0);

    if(lpFileBase==0)
    {
        std::cout<<"\n MapViewOfFile failed \n";
        CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return 1;
    }

    dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER) lpFileBase;
    if(dosHeader->e_magic==IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
    {
        std::cout<<"\n DOS Signature (MZ) Matched \n";

        peHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS) ((u_char*)dosHeader+dosHeader->e_lfanew);
        if(peHeader->Signature==IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
        {
            std::cout<<"\n PE Signature (PE) Matched \n";
            sectionHeader = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(peHeader);
            UINT nSectionCount = peHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections;

            //No of Sections
            std::cout<<"\n No of Sections : "<<nSectionCount<<"  \n";

            //sectionHeader contains pointer to first section
            //sectionHeader++ will move to next section
            for( UINT i=0; i<nSectionCount; ++i, ++sectionHeader )
            {
                std::cout<<"\n-----------------------------------------------\n";
                std::cout<<"\n Section Name : "<<sectionHeader->Name<<" \n";
                //address can be obtained as (PBYTE)lpFileBase+sectionHeader->PointerToRawData
                std::cout<<"\n Size of section data : "<<sectionHeader->Misc.VirtualSize<<" \n";
                std::cout<<"\n-----------------------------------------------\n";
            }

            //Now sectionHeader will have pointer to last section
            //if you add sectionHeader++ in for loop instead of ++sectionHeader it will point to memory after last section

        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just do it the wrong way.
I wrote some code for you, hope it helps.It can show the data of the last section of a PE file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <windows.h>

void ShowHexData(BYTE *ptr,DWORD len)
{
    int index = 0;
    int i = 0;
    const int width = 16;
    while(index + width < len)
    {
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < width; ++i)
        {
            printf(" %02X",ptr[index + i]);
        }
        printf("    \t");
        for(i = 0; i < width; ++i)
        {
            if(ptr[index + i] >= 0x20 &&
                        ptr[index + i] <= 0x7F)
            {
                putchar(ptr[index + i]);
            }else{
                putchar('.');
            }
        }
        index += width;
        putchar('\n');
    }

    for(i = 0; index  + i < len; ++ i)
    {
        printf(" %02X",ptr[index + i]);
    }
    while(i < width)
    {
        printf("   ");
        i += 1;
    }
    printf("    \t");
    for(i = 0; index + i < len; ++ i)
    {
        if(ptr[index + i] >= 0x20 &&
                    ptr[index + i] <= 0x7F)
        {
            putchar(ptr[index + i]);
        }else{
            putchar('.');
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');


}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage : %s filename\n",argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }else{
        FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1],"rb");
        IMAGE_DOS_HEADER DosHeader = {0};
        IMAGE_FILE_HEADER FileHeader = {0};
        IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER SectionHeader = {0};
        DWORD Signature = 0;
        DWORD RawPointerToPeHeader = 0, SizeOfFile = 0;
        DWORD SectionCount = 0;
        DWORD ByteCount = 0;
        BYTE *pData = NULL;
        if(!fp)
        {
            perror("");
            return -1;
        }
        fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
        SizeOfFile = ftell(fp);
        if(SizeOfFile <
            sizeof(IMAGE_DOS_HEADER) + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS))
            goto not_pe_file;
        fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);
        fread(&DosHeader,1,sizeof DosHeader,fp);
        if(DosHeader.e_magic != 'M' + 'Z' * 256)
            goto not_pe_file;
        RawPointerToPeHeader = DosHeader.e_lfanew;
        if(SizeOfFile <=
            RawPointerToPeHeader + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS))
            goto not_pe_file;
        fseek(fp,RawPointerToPeHeader,SEEK_SET);
        fread(&Signature,1,sizeof(DWORD),fp);
        if(Signature != 'P' + 'E' * 256)
            goto not_pe_file;
        fread(&FileHeader,1,sizeof FileHeader,fp);
        if(FileHeader.SizeOfOptionalHeader !=
            sizeof(IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER))
            goto not_pe_file;
        SectionCount = FileHeader.NumberOfSections;
        if(SectionCount == 0)
        {
            printf("No section for this file.\n");
            fclose(fp);
            return -1;
        }
        if(SizeOfFile <=
            RawPointerToPeHeader +
            sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS) +
            SectionCount * sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER))
            goto not_pe_file;
        fseek(fp,
            RawPointerToPeHeader + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS) +
            (SectionCount - 1) * sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER),
                SEEK_SET);
        fread(&SectionHeader,1,sizeof SectionHeader,fp);

        ByteCount = SectionHeader.Misc.VirtualSize < SectionHeader.PointerToRawData ?
            SectionHeader.Misc.VirtualSize : SectionHeader.PointerToRawData;

        if(ByteCount == 0)
        {
            printf("No data to read for target section.\n");
            fclose(fp);
            return -1;
        }else if(ByteCount + SectionHeader.PointerToRawData > SizeOfFile)
        {
            printf("Bad section data.\n");
            fclose(fp);
            return -1;
        }
        fseek(fp,SectionHeader.PointerToRawData,SEEK_SET);

        pData = (BYTE*)malloc(ByteCount);

        fread(pData,1,ByteCount,fp);

        ShowHexData(pData,ByteCount);
        free(pData);
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;


not_pe_file:
        printf("Not a PE file.\n");
        fclose(fp);
        return -1;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

In short, you do not know where the data is, until you analyze the data according to the file header.

Answer (score 0):

sections pointer:

```
PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER pish = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(pinh); // definition in winnt.h
```

or

```
PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER pish = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)((DWORD)pioh + pifh->SizeOfOptionalHeader);
```

the last section pointer is:

```
PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER pilsh = &pish[pifh->NumberOfSections-1];
```