# Getting virtual address of PE header in memory

Tags: c++, winapi

So generally, people say that all you have to do to get the PE header address is sth. like this:

```
IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* IDH = (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*)GetModuleHandle(NULL);

IMAGE_NT_HEADERS * INT = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *)((int *)IDH + (int)IDH.e_lfanew);
```

However, after several hours of thinking why it doesn't work for me, I realized that I additionally need to divide IDH.e_lfanew by 4. So I get the correct pointer to IMAGE_NT_HEADER struct only in this way:

```
IMAGE_NT_HEADERS * INT = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *)((int *)IDH + (int)(IDH.e_lfanew/4));
```

Could somebody explain to me why do I need to divide it? My OS is Windows 8 64 bit. Maybe my version of windows is the reason? Anyway, I would be very grateful for any guidance!

Comment: Same mistake as [Loading PE Headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782771/loading-pe-headers)

Comment: I believe if you change this (int*) to a (int) you wont need to divide by 4...Probably just a pointer issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are adding `IDH.e_lfanew` to an `int *`, where each element is 4 bytes long, and I expect that `e_lfanew` is the byte-offset, not the number of `int` into the structure.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the reason