# Explanation of the signature address shift in PE file

Tags: c++

i have found that to check for the "PE" string into a file i can't just fill the IMAGE_NT_HEADERS struct with the data from the file i want to read, but i have to shift the byte in this way:

```
ntHeader = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *) (dosHeader->e_lfanew + (DWORD) dosHeader);
```

There is also the (DWORD) cast that is not very clear because the compiler doesn't throw error
(obviously it doesn't work when it came to check the PE format).
I've checked everywhere [also in stackoverflow :)] and this line appear always but i can't found an answer to my question.

Thanks for your time.
Bye !

Comment: http://www.csn.ul.ie/~caolan/publink/winresdump/winresdump/doc/pefile2.html

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx

Comment: You are making exactly the same mistake as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782771/loading-pe-headers)

Answer (score 0):

The NT header is at the offset given by `e_lfaNew` (in bytes) from the top of the file. Since the DOS header is the first thing in the .exe file, one way of finding the NT header is like this (stylistic ugliness notwithstanding):

```
ntHeader = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *) (((uint8_t *)dosHeader) + dosHeader->e_lfaNew);
```

This treats the DOS header pointer as a base byte pointer and adds to it the byte offset required.