# add new section to a pe file in c++

Tags: c++, file, portable-executable

i have some problem to create a simple packer in c++.
i need to add new section to the pe file to do this i want to initialize a new section.i using below code in visual studio 2015:

```
PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER new_section;
new_section->Characteristics = IMAGE_SCN_MEM_WRITE;
```

but it gives me new_section being used without being initialized,how can i fix this?

and i want to know how should i add the section to pe file after initializing,should i use memset function?
thanks for helping.

Comment: If VS shows an error message, could you post the exact message?

Comment: Where do you initialize new_section? Nowhere? That's probably the reason compiler warns you about it...

Comment: well i said the exact message

Comment: ok,then how should i initialize it?!

Answer (score 1):

You did not initialize the `PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER` pointer (note it is a pointer to struct). Since it is a struct, you need to convert your data to it, assuming your data is stored in `buffer`:

```
PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pidh = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)buffer;
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pinh = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((BYTE*)pidh + pidh->e_lfanew);
PIMAGE_FILE_HEADER pifh = (PIMAGE_FILE_HEADER)&pinh->FileHeader;
PIMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER pioh = (PIMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER)&pinh->OptionalHeader;
PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER new_section = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)((BYTE*)pinh + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS));
```

this usage example is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8783114/6575931).

Comment: i use your code and it gives error: cannot convert from 'PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER *' to 'PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER'

Comment: Not familiar with the library, so just asking: does it have a constructor, or is it just POD which new just allocates but leaves uninitialized?

Comment: @Uriel Eli most of the c++ code using this struct,and its gettin a little hard if i want change that,beside of that i serached a lot for good tutorial to create a packer in c++,but there is not any good tutorial,i just find lots of sporadics informations.

Comment: @alex how are you using it if you didnt give it any contents?

Comment: @Uriel Eli i used something like that u mentioned,but the main problem is i need add my own section with my own detals,any idea for doing this?!

Comment: @alex I've not work with this before, but of course you can. use the example above as to the rates of bits shift (allocations and other headers), enter your own data like you did on the second line of your code, and save it back.

Comment: you can always use reinterpretcast to bring it back to `buffer` and save it to the file.