# Getting base address and size of the .text section using WINAPI

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to find a way to get the base address and size of the code (.text) section using winapi. I believe that this can be done using the IMAGE_DOS_HEADER/IMAGE_NT_HEADERS structures?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47880244/920069 may help.

Comment: A PE images generally store addresses as RVAs (relative virtual addresses). By looking at the file contents alone, you cannot determine the final address in virtual address space. This only becomes available once the loader is done loading the image. It's also not clear, what size you are looking for. There are 2 sizes here: The size of the section as well as the space requirements when mapped into memory. Which one are you looking for?